# https request from heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, https

I am tying to get data from vk.com api via https protocol. like this ([api vk docs](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BA_API)):

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=' + global['access_token'], function (d) {
  var chunk = '';
  d.on('data', function (data) {
    chunk += data;
  });

  d.on('end', function () {
    console.log(chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

but in heroku logs I see

```
Error: Protocol:https: not supported.
```

So, how can I get this data? My app work in http protocol, this is config:

```
var express = require('express'),
  routes = require('./routes');

var app = express();

    app.configure(function () {
      app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
      app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
      app.set('view engine', 'jade');
      app.use(express.favicon());
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    });

    app.configure('development', function () {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    app.get('/', routes.index);

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
      console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });
```

Comment: are you specifying the node version in your package.json?  Older versions of node only had `https.get` with an options param, not a string.

Comment: yes, I write "node": "0.8.x". on local machine all works correct

Answer (score 0):

Node v0.8.9 added the functionality to make https.get() accept a URL.

Unless you have a very specific reason, use "node": "0.10.x" under engines in package.json.

Also try:

`var options = {
    host: 'api.vk.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/method/users.get?access_token=' + global['access_token']
  };

https.get('options', function(....`